# Is the maxclients setting in apache config file accurate?

Tags: linux, centos

In the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, the maxclients parameter is set to 10.

However, I can run 20 concurrent persistent connections (on separate Chrome Tabs) with no errors.

I am using the EventSource javascript object to create the persistent connections. Each Chrome tab has a different persistent connection, which receives an incremented number every second from the server.

I am also using the following PHP command to display the number of Server Connections on each Chrome tab:
exec("netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l");

Strangely, the Server Connections is always shown as '2'. Is there a lag in that command, or does it consider multiple connections from the same IP Address to be only one connection?

I am also monitoring the memory using shell_exec("free -m"), which shows a slight decrease in the cache size as persistent connections are added, but it doesn't get close to having to use a swap file.

I am using CentOS v. 6.10, 64 bit, with 2 GIG Ram, and a Xeon E3 processor (4 core; 3.1 ghz).

What is the best method for me to know the maximum concurrent persistent connections that I can run from my server?

---

Thank you for your replies. I am using Apache 2.4.39. There is no MaxRequestWorkers parameter in the httpd.conf file.

**Here are some additional questions:**

1. If the maxclients parameter is set to 10, why can I run 20 concurrent persistent connections on separate Chrome Tabs (as was described in my original post) with no errors?
2. Will the test that I am doing (concurrent persistent connections on separate Chrome Tabs) produce the same load on the server than if the website was run from 20 different IP addresses?
3. Why does the following 'Server Connections' command always show '2', when I am running 20 concurrent persistent connections: exec("netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l")

Here is the code that I am using to test:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['nCreateSocket']) {
    @DoCreateSocket();
    exit;
}

$sTemp = exec('uptime');
$asFields = explode("average: ", $sTemp);
$sData_ServerLoad = $asFields[1];

$nData_ServerConnections = exec("netstat -an | grep :80 | wc -l");

$sServerMemory = shell_exec("free -m");
$sServerMemory = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $sServerMemory);

$asFields = explode("Mem: ", $sServerMemory);
$asFields = explode(" ",$asFields[1]);
$nData_Memory_Used = $asFields[1];
$nData_Memory_Free = $asFields[2];
$nData_Memory_Cached = $asFields[5];
?>
<html>
<body onLoad=DoLoad()>
<script>
var gobjEventSource, gobjSpanAutoTest, da

function DoLoad() {
    da = document.all
    gobjSpanAutoTest = da.idSpanAutoTest
    DoCreateEventSource()
}

function DoCreateEventSource() {
    gobjEventSource = new EventSource("betting2019_ServerTest.php?nCreateSocket=1");
    gobjEventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        var sData = event.data
        gobjSpanAutoTest.innerHTML += sData + "<br>";
    };
    gobjEventSource.onerror = function(event) {
        gobjEventSource.close()
        alert("Connection Error")
    };
}
</script>

<?php
echo "nData_ServerConnections: $nData_ServerConnections";
echo "<br>sData_ServerLoad: $sData_ServerLoad";
echo "<br>nData_Memory_Used: $nData_Memory_Used";
echo "<br>nData_Memory_Free: $nData_Memory_Free";
echo "<br>nData_Memory_Cached: $nData_Memory_Cached";
?>
<br><br>
<span id=idSpanAutoTest></span>
</body>
</html>
<?php
function DoCreateSocket() {
    $gcnInactivitySeconds = 6000;
    $gnLastActivity = time();
    header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
    sleep(1);

    echo "data: 13\n\n";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    for ($nIndex = 0; $nIndex < 7200; $nIndex++) {
        echo "data: $nIndex\n\n";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(1);
        if (time() - $gnLastActivity > $gcnInactivitySeconds) {
            break;
        }
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Which MPM did you configure? And which one are you actually using?

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to be using PHP, I'd say that you're not using multi-threading on your setup.

It's better if you used another tools to check what the limits of your server actually are. For monitoring the server status you can enable the */server-status* adding this settings to your config and reloading the server:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Require local
</Location>
```

Then, you can use apachectl fullstatus to check the server status from the command line (you'd need to install links for it to work). You can also check /server-status from a browser, but you'd want to restrict access to that URL.

For testing purposes you can use Apache AB to stress the server. This software is usually installed along with Apache. Here I'm performing a test which makes 50000 requests with a concurrency of 25.

```
ab  -c 25 -n 50000  http://localhost/
```

I set a server with *Maxclients 5* and you can see that the server caps to 5 clients being served at the same time. Notice the line *5 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers*.

```
$ sudo apachectl fullstatus
                  Apache Server Status for localhost (via ::1)

   Server Version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
   Server MPM: prefork
   Server Built: Apr 24 2019 13:45:48
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Current Time: Thursday, 23-May-2019 22:59:32 CEST
   Restart Time: Thursday, 23-May-2019 22:57:40 CEST
   Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
   Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
   Server uptime: 1 minute 51 seconds
   Server load: 2.48 0.96 0.44
   Total accesses: 720593 - Total Traffic: 3.5 GB
   CPU Usage: u50.17 s48.82 cu0 cs0 - 89.2% CPU load
   6490 requests/sec - 32.5 MB/second - 5.1 kB/request
   5 requests currently being processed, 0 idle workers

 LCWCC

   Scoreboard Key:
   "_" Waiting for Connection, "S" Starting up, "R" Reading Request,
   "W" Sending Reply, "K" Keepalive (read), "D" DNS Lookup,
   "C" Closing connection, "L" Logging, "G" Gracefully finishing,
   "I" Idle cleanup of worker, "." Open slot with no current process

Srv PID   Acc             M CPU   SS Req Conn Child  Slot   Client VHost               Request
0-0 23945 1/141895/141895 C 19.52 0  0   5.1  709.76 709.76 ::1    maya.localdomain:80 GET / HTTP/1.0
1-0 23946 1/144708/144708 C 20.01 0  0   5.1  723.83 723.83 ::1    maya.localdomain:80 GET / HTTP/1.0                                                        
2-0 23947 0/146565/146565 W 20.04 0  0   0.0  733.12 733.12 ::1    maya.localdomain:80 GET /server-status HTTP/1.1                                                               
3-0 23948 1/141185/141185 C 19.50 0  0   5.1  706.21 706.21 ::1    maya.localdomain:80 GET / HTTP/1.0
4-0 23949 1/146240/146240 C 19.92 0  0   5.1  731.49 731.49 ::1    maya.localdomain:80 GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: I think what you are asking about tools to perform a load test. There are tools like [Apache Jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) which are better suited for this purpose. Then you'd need to carefully design a test plan.

Comment: Please see the additional 3 questions that I added to my original post.

Comment: In general, browser tabs are not a good way to perform load tests. You can't control how the browser will handle these connections. If you were able to perform the same test with netstat on the client side you'll realize that the browser is closing some of this connections once it receives the content from the server.

Answer (score 0):

MaxRequestWorkers was called MaxClients before Apache 2.3.13. The old name is still supported.

Limiting the number of processes to serve users prevents the server from swapping due to a shortage of RAM. The limit value is calculated by dividing the typical average memory use of an Apache process into the total percent of memory that you want to allocate to Apache.

1. Calculate a limit value for the MaxRequestWorkers (or MaxClients) and ServerLimit configuration variables as follows:

If your instance has more than 4 GB of RAM:

Divide the average %MEM value for Apache processes into 90%. For example, given an average %MEM value of 0.8%, divide 90% by 0.8%

0.9 / 0.008 = 112.5
Round the result down to the nearest whole number. In this case, the limit value is 112.

If your instance has 4 GB of RAM or less:

Divide the average %MEM value for Apache processes into 80%. For example, given an average %MEM value of 0.8%, divide 80% by 0.8% for a result of 100.

Note: These values are calculated with the assumption that the instance is a dedicated web server. If you are hosting other applications on the server, subtract the total percentage of memory used by these applications from either 90% or 80% before doing the calculation. Performance might decrease if you run other applications in addition to Apache on an instance with 4 GB of RAM or less.

2. Edit the instance's httpd.conf file, update the MaxClients (or MaxRequestWorkers) and ServerLimit configuration variables, and save your changes. For example:

MaxClients  112

ServerLimit 112

3. Restart the web server by running the service command from a terminal session:

service httpd graceful

Now browser tab could not assure you number of process open for each website, that could be multithreaded, If you want to count the process check ps for process and proc filesystem for thread.

Comment: Please see the additional 3 questions that I added to my original post.